# The difference of {sample} and {wildcard.sample} in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

Can anyone tell me the difference of `{sample}` and `{wildcard.sample}` in the snakemake official tutorial as below?
Do they both equal to "A" or "B" ?
I am wondering when to use `{sample}` and `{wildcard.sample}`.
Thanks!

```
SAMPLES = ["A", "B"]


rule all:
    input:
        "plots/quals.svg"


rule bwa_map:
    input:
        "data/genome.fa",
        "data/samples/{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input} | samtools view -Sb - > {output}"


rule samtools_sort:
    input:
        "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
    output:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "samtools sort -T sorted_reads/{wildcards.sample} "
        "-O bam {input} > {output}"


rule samtools_index:
    input:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.bam"
    output:
        "sorted_reads/{sample}.bam.bai"
    shell:
        "samtools index {input}"


rule bcftools_call:
    input:
        fa="data/genome.fa",
        bam=expand("sorted_reads/{sample}.bam", sample=SAMPLES),
        bai=expand("sorted_reads/{sample}.bam.bai", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        "calls/all.vcf"
    shell:
        "samtools mpileup -g -f {input.fa} {input.bam} | "
        "bcftools call -mv - > {output}"


rule plot_quals:
    input:
        "calls/all.vcf"
    output:
        "plots/quals.svg"
    script:
        "scripts/plot-quals.py"
```

Comment: You may be interested in the answers to this other similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65854634/1878788

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snakemake: Difference between wildcard.wildcard\_name and {wildcard}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854634/snakemake-difference-between-wildcard-wildcard-name-and-wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

{sample} is used in "input" or "output", and {wildcard.sample} is used in "shell", because only {wildcard.sample} retrive the actual sample name and transfer to the shell, then the command in your shell will run. I think.